# Start felix-framework-5.2.0 on android

Tags: android, osgi, apache-felix

I try to start `elix-framework-5.2.0` on `Android` device
 `config.properties` standard with added:

```
 felix.auto.start.1=\
 file:bundle/org.apache.felix.bundlerepository-2.0.4.jar \
 file:bundle/org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.14.0.jar \
 file:bundle/org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.10.0.jar \
 file:bundle/org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.16.2.jar \
 file:bundle/org.apache.felix.scr-2.0.0.jar \
 file:bundle/org.apache.felix.http.jetty-2.2.0.jar \
 file:bundle/org.apache.felix.http.api-2.3.2.jar \
 file:bundle/org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api-1.1.2.jar \
```

When start Apache Felix throws error:

```
Problem creating boot delegation class loader: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTarge
tException
Auto-properties install: file:bundle/org.apache.felix.bundlerepository-2.0.4.jar
 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not u
nique: org.apache.felix.bundlerepository:2.0.4)
Auto-properties install: file:bundle/org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.14.0.jar (o
rg.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not uniq
ue: org.apache.felix.gogo.command:0.14.0)
Auto-properties install: file:bundle/org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.10.0.jar (org
.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique
: org.apache.felix.gogo.shell:0.10.0)
```

.........

```
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.felix.scr [8] Error starting file:/data/felix/bundle/or
g.apache.felix.scr-2.0.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to reso
lve org.apache.felix.scr [8](R 8.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.scr [
8](R 8.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[
org.apache.felix.scr [8](R 8.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.scr [8](R
 8.0): missing requirement [org.apache.felix.scr [8](R 8.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee
=JavaSE)(version=1.6)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.scr [8](R 8.0
)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:411
4)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2111)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1365)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStart
LevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
[INFO] Started jetty 6.1.x at port(s) HTTP:8090
```

Anyone else got this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two main problems here.
First of all, you obtain

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle symbolic name and version are not unique
```

since some Bundles you included within **felix.auto.start** property are not necessary because already included within the framework you are embedding. Just try to remove conflicting Bundles and you will solve the problem.

Second, you have obtained missing requirements errors

```
... (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.felix.scr [8](R 8.0): missing requirement ...
```

because of the presence of the specified requirement

```
(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))
```

which tells you need a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) >= 1.6 for the execution of SCR, but of course no JRE are provided by Android, since it works with DVK or ART. To fix this problem:

1. enter SCR jar file;
2. open its MANIFEST.MF file;
3. remove the entire row **Require-Capability: (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))** or something similar (the exact syntax depends by the tool you used to generate the jar)
4. update the archive with the new MANIFEST.MF file;
5. use the updated archive as SCR Bundle to embed within OSGi framework.